# add leading 0 at a specific position in a string (R)

Tags: r, regex, string, leading-zero

I have a list of strings of this kind:

```
f<-c("CC 982","RX 112","TR 002","FF 1328")
```

I need to add a leading 0, as with the `str_pad` function, at the beginning of the numerical portion, to get to this:

```
"CC 0982" "RX 0112" "TR 0002" "FF 1328"
```

For now, I have tried with `sub`

```
sub('(.{2})(.{1})(.{3})', "\\1\\20\\3", f)
```

Close enough, but I don't want the leading 0 if the numerical string has 4 digits. What is the solution here?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can split the string by space and then use `sprintf` to join the components

```
d1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(f, "\\s+"))
sprintf("%s %04d", d1[,1], as.numeric(d1[,2]))
#[1] "CC 0982" "RX 0112" "TR 0002" "FF 1328"
```

---

Or with `gsubfn/sprintf` we get the expected output

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(x)), f)
#[1] "CC 0982" "RX 0112" "TR 0002" "FF 1328"
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `sub` you could modify to

```
sub("(\\D*)(\\b\\d{1,3}\\b)", "\\10\\2", f)
# [1] "CC 0982" "RX 0112" "TR 0002" "FF 1328"
```

This will only catch numbers up until 3 digits and modify them